# Android Google Maps V2 - Sd card as Tile Provider

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android app using Google Maps API V2 and i have to use offline tiles, i have all tiles (from open street maps in png format) of my entire city in my SD Card.
I already tried to use TileProvider Interface but didn't work.
How can i do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the way to do it. It works for me in a similar manner in my app. I guess you path returned by getTileFilename is wrong. Have you tried to write it out? Have you checked that you get the path to the right file? My guess is that you should use getAbsolutePath instead of getPath on getExternalStorageDirectory but that's just a guess.

Comment: @GuilhermeRuiz which `open street maps` have you used? And from where did you download the tiles?

Comment: @UmerFarooq I used this one http://www.openstreetmap.org/ and I downloaded the tiles using MOBAC (http://mobac.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I modified somethings and it worked. Here is the code:

**CustomMapTileProvider.java**

```
public class CustomMapTileProvider implements TileProvider {
    private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 256;
    private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;

    Override
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        byte[] image = readTileImage(x, y, zoom);
        return image == null ? null : new Tile(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, image);
    }

    private byte[] readTileImage(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        FileInputStream in = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = null;

        try { in = new FileInputStream(getTileFile(x, y, zoom));
            buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            while ((nRead = in .read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            buffer.flush();
            return buffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if ( in != null)
                try { in .close();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
            if (buffer != null)
                try {
                    buffer.close();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    }

    private File getTileFile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String tileFile = "/TILES_FOLDER/" + zoom + '/' + x + '/' + y + ".png";
        File file = new File(sdcard, tileFile);
        return file;
    }
}
```

**Add TileOverlay to your GoogleMap instance**

```
...

map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
TileOverlayOptions tileOverlay = new TileOverlayOptions();
tileOverlay.tileProvider(new CustomMapTileProvider());
map.addTileOverlay(tileOverlay).setZIndex(0);

...
```

Comment: You pass AssetManager and Context in the constructor and never use them.

Comment: @Spartako Oh, thank you! I was doing some tests using Context and i forgot to remove it.

Comment: @GuilhermeRuiz, what should be place in asset folder( tiles file ?), where to get it or download it ?